# My phone can't get GPS signal?

Tags: pokemon-go

I downloaded Pokémon Go on my LG Spirit yesterday and struggled to get it working because the GPS signal lost popping up..it worked after a few tries but after the 2nd time I get the same problem...today I tried the whole day on different locations and still that GPS signal lost keeps popping up. I tried all the android fixes and all my settings is correct even my google maps is updating and always running in the back.

Please help?

Comment: This seems like it might fit Android.se more.

Comment: Same problem here, my GPS actually works perfectly fine in google maps, traces my steps perfectly, but pokemon GO can't find me for some reason. Everything is enabled and set to high accuracy. Apparently  NOT allowing mock data location is supposed to help but it didn't fix anything for me =/.

Comment: Mock GPS in developer options must be turned off and of course any fake GPS app as well.

Comment: and try turning Location on off in setting and apps permission

Comment: I had this problem (on a newly reset phone), and tried all the fixes -- nothing worked.
Eventually, updating the Google Maps to the latest version application solved it. This also triggered an update of some Google Play services. Perhaps Pokémon is using some google maps components under the covers? I'm a complete Android n00b, so I wouldn't know. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The most common problem is an app or a setting to fake GPS data. The game is pretty good in detecting them. The result is that error.
Downloading Offline Maps or running Google Maps won't help getting a better GPS signal. It's just for performance & traffic reasons.

You'll probably have checked most of it, but better safe than sorry...

1. If you have a GPS faking app, turn it off.
2. Make sure Mock GPS is turned off by checking the Developer Options:

   - Go to Settings, scroll down to *About phone*.
   - Click a couple of times on the *Build number* Button. After a few times it will start a countdown to accept you as a Developer.
   - Go back to the last menu, there you'll find the Developer Options.
   - Disable *Allow Mock Locations* (This might have a slightly different name in other Android versions).

Of course make sure you have GPS enabled and allowed the app to use it. Google maps doesn't necessarily need GPS. It's just more accurate with it enabled.

3. Check GPS setting:

   - Settings -> Location (Make sure it's on)
   - In the Location menu set it to high accuracy.